# Android:When does the .APK file gets generated?

Tags: android

When we click on run and the emulator is not online (or not open) will the .apk file get generated or not?or it only gets generated when the emulator is online?Just for knowledge!!

Comment: The apk file is created before the emulator is launched.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generating the Apk is not depend upon emulator open or not. It is totally different process you just build the application then also your .apk file will generate and that we can used inside the mobile. When we generating the apk first all java api from program compressed into apk file. So the final conclusion is that generation of apk is not depend upon the Emulator.